# Забрать move семантикой строку из stringstream

Tags: c++

Чтобы сформировать строку использую [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)
(набиваю содержимым оператором `<<`), затем выбираю полученную строку методом 
[std::stringstream::str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "foo" << 42 << "bar";
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Исходный объект std::stringstream далее не используется, но при этом занимает память. Есть ли возможность использовать move-семантику, чтобы "забрать" у  std::stringstream его строку (в примере несущественно, в реальной задаче сейчас набивается строка в несколько сот мегабайт)?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Move the string out of a std::ostringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266525/move-the-string-out-of-a-stdostringstream). Хорошего ответа по ссылке нет, так что я бы сказал, что нормального способа сделать это нет.

Comment: Очистить поток. На худой конец расположить поток в свободной памяти оператором new а после использования удалить оператором delete. Или нужно вообще обойтись без копирования строк? Тогда не забирать строку из потока, а работать с объектом потока ss.str().

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Да, не хотелось бы лишнего копирования. Если же работать с ss.str() напрямую, то каждый такой вызов будет создавать копию ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/str/)).

Comment: Учитывая, что у Вас весьма специфичная задача (несколько сот мегабайт), на мой взгляд, использование `std::stringstream` нецелесообразно.

Comment: @ixSci Пока из альтернатив вижу boost karma, но хотелось бы иметь интерфейс ostream (много имеющегося кода его ожидает).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, если с boost'ом, то как на счёт варианта по ссылке с  `bio::stream_buffer<bio::back_insert_device<std::string> >`

Comment: @pepsicoca1: `str()` возвращает свой результат "по значению", а не "по ссылке". Поэтому работая с `ss.str()` "напрямую" вы не достигнете никакой экономии. Скорее наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Внешняя спецификация класса `std::strinstream` никак не утверждает, что внутри объекта `std::strinstream` хранится "готовый к употреблению" объект `std::string`. Поэтому не приходится ожидать, что вам удастся "забрать" содержимое `std::strinstream` в `std::string` при помощи move semantics.

То есть в общем случае избавиться от этапа построения объекта `std::string` на основе текущего содержимого `std::strinstream` не получится.

Метод `std::strinstream::str()` возвращает свой результат по значению. Если при реализации этого метода компилятор применит оптимизацию возвращаемого значения (RVO), то результат `ss.str()` будет сконструирован прямо в вашем объекте `s`. В противном случае будет сконструирован и возвращен временный объект типа `std::string`, который вы уже заберете в свой `s` при помощи move semantics. Это, наверное, единственное место, где тут может сработать move semantics.

P.S. В свете вышесказанного ясно, что не получится ничего достичь, работая с `ss.str()` "напрямую". Для этого все равно придется конструировать результат `ss.str()`. А в этом и заключается проблема, т.е. это ничего не экономит.

Answer (score 0):

Были еще старые строковые потоки не stringstream а strstream. Если мне не изменяет память, то у них после применения str() внутри замораживалась строка, и пользователю отдавался указатель на замороженную строку в виде char*. Если применить эти потоки, то лишнего копирования не будет. Правда они вроде-бы объявлены устаревшими.

Еще вариант - написать самодельный поток.